# django 1.6 Why not just 'user.last_login = timezone.now()' and 'user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])'?

Tags: django

The django `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py` ,fucntion **login** is:

```
def login(request, user):
    """
    Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
    have to reauthenticate on every request. Note that data set during
    the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.
    """
    if user is None:
        user = request.user
    # TODO: It would be nice to support different login methods, like signed cookies.
    if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
        if request.session[SESSION_KEY] != user.pk:
            # To avoid reusing another user's session, create a new, empty
            # session if the existing session corresponds to a different
            # authenticated user.
            request.session.flush()
    else:
        request.session.cycle_key()
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk
    request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        request.user = user
    rotate_token(request)
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
```

As you can see, the last line is to update the user field 'last_login' .It uses the signal mechanism and it is really very complicated. There is a large block of code behind this line, it is so large that I don't want to paste it here. If you are interested, you can [click here](http://note.youdao.com/share/?id=4186248d96cf3056c17344cea7848388&type=note) to see it.

Why not just use the two lines below instead of that magic line?

```
def login(request, user):
    #....
    rotate_token(request)
    user.last_login = timezone.now()
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the signal, you can hook into login process, without modifying `django.contrib.auth` code.

[This ticket from django trac](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5612) contains discussion about login/logout signal.

Related commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/132afbf8eee837b6fe2d051f7eced4889e19de88